# Backend TCA field dynamically fill of other field

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x

I have two TCA fields as type DateTime.

Field1 and Field2.

A date and time is selected for field1.

The value of field 1 must automatically be in the Field2. (default value)
But the value for field 2 must be changed.

The date for the Field2 must be for next week on Wednesday.

```
**Example 1:**

Field1:05-04-2018 17:00 

Field2 becomes: 05-09-2018 17:00


**Example 2:**

Field1:05-14-2018 12:00 

Field2 becomes: 05-23-2018 12:00
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

it might be easier to write an individual getter without an own field as the value can be computet from field1 directly.

then you might cache the value for the lifetime of the object. don't forget to clear the cache on a new setting of `field1`.

or you modify the setter of `field1` to also compute and set the value of `field2`.

Comment: I would like to do it directly in the backend. When the date is selected. 
I think via jquery. Is there an example of how I can use jquery?

Comment: you probably can do it, but I have no experience. on the other hand: a javascript fill of an editable field would enable manipulation of the value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.